# share a directory on the network using NSIS

Tags: windows, nsis

I want to share a directory on my computer on the network using NSIS. Is there a way to achieve it.

I want to share `C:\Temp as \\MYNAME\app\` using NSIS

Answer (score 2):

You can simply execute the command line as :

```
nsExec::ExecToLog 'NET SHARE app="C:\Temp" /GRANT:Username,FULL'
```

Where username is windows user that can access the folder, similarly you can use Everyone, $, etc.

Comment: Confirmed this method works on Windows 10 family OSes, which the macros in NSIS's wiki do not.

Answer (score 0):

There are some macros in the NSIS wiki to [share folders](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sharing_Folders). They are stated to work up to Windows 2008.